# Dotproject

Tags: email, gmail, ssl, dotproject

I Have install dot project on linux machine. using ssmtp for gmail account to sending emails for mails notifications . but when i create any user it doesn't send mails to user email ID for account creation. but i send maail form shell prompt.the error i am getting is Failed to send email: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 22sm11794837wfd.6 added :( . Please help me if any one have solution....

Answer (score 1):

Gmail requires a secure connection (TLS or SSL).

You need to configure SSMPT (not dotProject) to talk securely with Google's SMTP server.

I think you can just add the following to your ssmtp.conf file and (assuming your SSMTP package was compiled with SSL support) it should then work:

```
UseTLS=YES
```

Or perhaps:

```
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

More info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf).

Comment: didn't know/see ssmtp ;) upping your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first." means that you have to connect with TLS (Transport Layer Security). Does dot project support that?